# Evenly distributing buttons in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

I have 4 buttons which are supposed to be at the bottom of my screen, right next to each other -- 0 pixels apart. I want it to work for any screen size, or at least for iPhone 5, 6, and 6+. I'm trying to add constraints, but it doesn't do what I want it to do.

It's my first time working with Swift and XCode, please give me a hint.

[image: Application]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If my answer helped you, don't forget to mark it as accepted, so it'll help others

Answer (score 3):

The best practice is to use UIStackView

- Just drop it to storyboard
- Add vertical spacing constraint to bottom layout guide
- Add horizontal spacing constraints to leading and trailing of the superview
- Add height constraint
- Now add the buttons as subviews of the stack view
- set the stack views properties: Horizontal, distribution and alignment as you want

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Options are:

- Set up constraints correctly
- Use a StackView
- Use a TabBar format
- Use a ToolBar

Or, complex-ish calculations in code.

Answer (score 0):

Select all of the buttons in interface builder so they're all highlighted and bring up the "Add New Constraints" popover. Add the left, right, and bottom constraints, and check "Equal Widths".